# Работа с xml

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
В приложении у меня есть главное окно (main.xml) и есть руководство о программе (guide.xml). Как сделать, чтобы руководство запускалось поверх главного окна?

Comment: я только начал разбератся, но каждое окно - это активити, потому врятли можно запускать одно поверх другого, разве, что выносить текст в каком-то диалоге или картинкой и потом его прятать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если руководство по программе - это небольшая справка (текст), то проще всего сделать [диалог](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) (либо custom, либо alert).

Comment: Это так. Интересует, как его запустить поверх активити?

Comment: что значит поверх? тебе надо перед запуском приложения его запускать? или при нажатии кнопки? если при нажатии выводить в диалог - будет поверх

Comment: Диалог сам собой запустится поверх активности, никаких особых действий для этого делать не надо.